# How do I break rotten boulders?

Tags: stone

I have a lot of rocks around my house. Generally, I drill holes with a rotary hammer and then use wedges and feathers to split them. There are some that are rotten, however, and the wedge and feathers just blow out. They are massive, and breaking then with a jackhammer would take a long time. Is there another option? I think that if I could saw them or something, it would be easier.

Comment: I really want the answer to be something about explosives...  Obvious answer is to rent a bigger jack hammer.  Are you looking for any certain method?  Trying to use basic tools that you have already?

Comment: What does rotten mean in this context?

Comment: Crumbly. Disintegrating.

Comment: How bigger is bigger?

Answer (score 2):

Rent a [mini hoe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waCyRL3kDMA) or [skid loader](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSgWLu1dyuE) with a hammer attachment for a day. Git 'r done.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tjSwJmH1HI) from PBS' "This Old House"

It appears that the OP tried the feather and wedge approach, however, they could try larger ones and more powerful hammer.... Basically drill holes, put the feather in, drive the wedge until it splits. The larger the boulder, the larger the feather and wedge and hammer force needed.

Comment: You may wish to describe the techniques used in the video you linked. Links go bad over time and can make this answer useless.

Comment: Tools for How to Remove a Boulder: - pointed shovel, used to dig around rock - electric rotary hammer and 1/2-inch-diameter masonry bit, used to drive screws and drill screw holes - bulb-type syringe, for blowing dust out of holes - feathers and wedges, used to split the rock - 3-pound sledgehammer, for pounding in the wedges - long-handled pry bar, used to break off split pieces of rock - diesel-powered air compressor and rotary rock hammer, for drilling and splitting large rocks